# How to wake up stunned parrot in deponia?

Tags: deponia

How to wake up stunned parrot in deponia?

The parrot was stunned with laughing gas and needs to be wakened up, how do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a pretty obvious item. You'll need it to wake other things as well (like Goal). So if Goal is still sleeping, you shouldn't worry about the parrot. If Goal is awake, you should have the right item.

> It's the Espresso (the same waking up Goal).